# Group By Eloquent ORM

Tags: laravel, group-by, laravel-4, eloquent

I was searching for making a `GROUP BY name` [Eloquent ORM docs](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent) but I haven't find anything, neither on google.

Does anyone know if it's possible ? or should I use query builder ?

Comment: If the query-builder support it, i can see groupBy, doesn't that count for eloquent the same then? If you can use it on the query bulder you can use it on elequent? At least that is what i was thinking.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Eloquent uses the query builder internally, so you can do:

```
$users = User::orderBy('name', 'desc')
                ->groupBy('count')
                ->having('count', '>', 100)
                ->get();
```

Comment: Additionnaly, do you know if we can `GROUP BY YEAR(datetimefield)` ?

Comment: Probably you will have to use RAW in this case: `groupBy(DB::raw('YEAR(datetimefield)'))`

Answer (score 10):

## Laravel 5

> **WARNING**: As @Usama stated in comments section, this groups by AFTER fetching data from the database. The grouping is not done by the database server.
> *I wouldn't recommend this solution for large data set.*

This is working for me (i use **laravel 5.6**).

```
$collection = MyModel::all()->groupBy('column');
```

If you want to convert the collection to plain php array, you can use **toArray()**

```
$array = MyModel::all()->groupBy('column')->toArray();
```

Comment: Just a warning: This groups by AFTER fetching data from the database. The grouping is not done by the database server.

Comment: this is dont work for me the error is :  array_key_exists(): The first argument should be either a string or an integer

Answer (score 3):

try: `->unique('column')`

example:

`$users = User::get()->unique('column');`