# If statement in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have two Models which are joined through three id's to one 1 id. The model `AdviceProtocol` had three ids defined: `threshold_category1_id`, `threshold_category2_id` and `threshold_category3_id`. These are all three linked to `id` from the model `Categories`. The threshold_cateogry_id's can be a number linked to the `categories.id`, or null.

In my query, I need to go through three of the `threshold_catogory_ids` and if they are `NOT NULL`, retrieve the `categories.name`. The query that I have now:

```
$advicePreparationsQuery = AdviceProtocol::select(['advice_protocols.name', 'advice_protocols.category', 'questions.name AS question_name', 'categories.name as Category_Name','categories.name as Category_Name2'])
            ->join('questions', 'advice_protocols.user_goal_id', '=', 'questions.id')
            ->join('categories', function ($join)
            {
                $join->on('advice_protocols.threshold_category1_id', '=', 'categories.id')->orOn('advice_protocols.threshold_category2_id', '=', 'categories.id')->orOn('advice_protocols.threshold_category3_id', '=', 'categories.id');
            })
```

This query now returns the same `category.name` twice.
I have tried to look up how other people have solved this problem, but i couldn't find something accurate online.

Comment: I think you need a join to the categories table for each category, so you need 3 joins to the categories table.

Comment: I have tried to define 3 joins, each seperate for the threshold_category but this gives an error :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try three joins with three different alias and then grab the name for each category name of each different alias:

```
$advicePreparationsQuery = AdviceProtocol::select(['advice_protocols.name', 'advice_protocols.category', 'questions.name AS question_name', 'categories1.name as Category_Name','categories2.name as Category_Name2','categories3.name as Category_Name2'])
            ->join('questions', 'advice_protocols.user_goal_id', '=', 'questions.id')
            ->join('categories as categories1', 'advice_protocols.threshold_category1_id', '=', 'categories1.id')
            ->join('categories as categories2', 'advice_protocols.threshold_category2_id', '=', 'categories2.id')
            ->join('categories as categories3', 'advice_protocols.threshold_category3_id', '=', 'categories3.id');
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried this too, but left out the `as cateogries#` so I got an error.

Answer (score 0):

Use group by name in query  ie `->groupBy('category.name')`

```
$advicePreparationsQuery = AdviceProtocol::select(['advice_protocols.name', 'advice_protocols.category', 'questions.name AS question_name', 'categories.name as Category_Name','categories.name as Category_Name2'])
        ->join('questions', 'advice_protocols.user_goal_id', '=', 'questions.id')
        ->join('categories', function ($join)
        {
            $join->on('advice_protocols.threshold_category1_id', '=', 'categories.id')->orOn('advice_protocols.threshold_category2_id', '=', 'categories.id')->orOn('advice_protocols.threshold_category3_id', '=', 'categories.id');
        }
       ->groupBy('category.name'))
```

Comment: The brackets are not adding up. Does the `->groupBy` need to be in de `function ($join)`?

Comment: Prepare your query like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22562223/2151290)

Comment: Got it working! But it still returns two the same `categories.name`

Comment: Why is your query only requesting two categories? Don't you need the three of them?

Comment: That is true, but adding the third calling of categories.name only retrieves the same categories.name thee times.. I need to select the categories.name based on the threshold id.