# How can I make a collection unique?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, unique

Here is my code:

```
$products = Products::orderBy('id')->get();
```

And here is my table:

```
// products
+----+----------+----------+
| id |  brand   |   name   |
+----+----------+----------+
| 1  | Cisco    | SF300-48 |
| 2  | Mikrotik | RB260GS  |
| 3  | Mikrotik | PoEhEX   |
+----+----------+----------+
```

Here is my code:

```
foreach($products as $product){
    echo $product->brand.PHP_EOL;
}
```

**Current result:**

```
/* Cisco
   Mikrotik 
   Mikrotik
```

**The expected result:**

```
/* Cisco
   Mikrotik
```

See? I need to make a laravel collection unique. `array_unique()` is for arrays and I cannot use it here. Any idea how can I do that?

Noted that I need to all names. *(I mean I need these values `SF300-48`, `RB260GS`, `PoEhEX`)*. So I cannot use `DISTINCT` in the query either.

Comment: Check [groupBy()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22562101/group-by-eloquent-orm).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`unique()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/collections#method-unique) method:

```
$products->unique('brand')
```

Comment: Oh .. the cleanest answer.

Comment: Haha, 71k karma and this may be the easiest answer you've ever written, Алексей. :p

Comment: @MartinAJ if you're talking about something like `@foreach($products->unique('brand') as $product)` then yes, it's totally fine.

Answer (score 1):

```
foreach($products->pluck('brand')->unique() as $brand){
    echo $brand . PHP_EOL;
}
```