# Duplicates as a relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I have a model called `debtors`. I'd like to have a relationship for all other debtors with the same `phone_home` and `phone_work` attributes.

I know I can do this:

```
public function dupes_phone_home()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Debtor', 'phone_home', 'phone_home');
}

public function dupes_phone_work()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Debtor', 'phone_work', 'phone_work');
}
```

How can I merge these two relationships into one so it can be used in eager loading, etc.?

**Edit:** example of what I want:

```
$debtor1 = Debtor::create([
    'name' => 'Joe Blow',
    'phone_home' => '123',
    'phone_work' => '456',
]);

$debtor2 = Debtor::create([
    'name' => 'Joe Blow Dupe 1',
    'phone_home' => '123',
    'phone_work' => '789',
]);

$debtor3 = Debtor::create([
    'name' => 'Joe Blow Dupe 2',
    'phone_home' => null,
    'phone_work' => '456',
]);

$joe_with_dupes = Debtor::with('dupes')->get()->toArray();
```

Would give me something like:

```
[
    'name' => 'Joe Blow',
    'phone_home' => '123',
    'phone_work' => '456',
    'dupes' => [
        [       
            'name' => 'Joe Blow Dupe 1',
            'phone_home' => '123',
            'phone_work' => '789',
        ],
        [       
            'name' => 'Joe Blow Dupe 2',
            'phone_home' => null,
            'phone_work' => '456',
        ],
    ],
],
[
    'name' => 'Joe Blow Dupe 1',
    'phone_home' => '123',
    'phone_work' => '789',
    'dupes' => [
        [       
            'name' => 'Joe Blow',
            'phone_home' => '123',
            'phone_work' => '456',
        ],
    ],
],
...
```

Comment: Do you really need a relationship for this, or should you just be using a self-join with a method?

Comment: You may be able to achieve this with just grouping in an Eloquent collection: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22562223/823549.

Comment: You do not need a relationship I believe, Its a same table where you need to collect specific results together. You can have `Debtor::groupBy('phone_home','phone_work')->get()`

Comment: I was thinking of a self-join, was curious if there was a more "eloquent" approach.

Comment: @KevinDion the only goal is to Eager Load both relationships? If so, you can do it like this: `Model::with(['dupes_phone_home', 'dupes_phone_work'])->get();`

Comment: The goal is to grab all the duplicates of a particular debtor, which is done by checking the `phone_home` and `phone_work` columns for the same value. I'd like this as a single relationship, called `dupes`, that I can eager load if possible.

Comment: @KevinDion This doesn't seem to be very difficult to accomplish but could you update your question attaching an example with values of your desired output? at the moment isn't very clear (imo).

Comment: I edited my OP. I hope this is clear enough.

Answer (score 0):

You could join this two relationships like this:

```php
class Debtor extends Model
{
    public function debtors()
    {
        return Debtor::where(function ($query) {
            return $query->where('phone_home', $this->phone_home)
                       ->orWhere('phone_work', $this->phone_work);
        }
    }

    public function getDebtorsAttribute()
    {
        return $this->debtors()->get();
    }

    // your relationships
}
```

### Note

This might not work with eager loading, so you could add this attribute (`debtors`) to your `$appends = [];` model config, but given that this relationships are a little bit off (same value for foreign and parent keys) this could lead to a recursive problem.