# Use Eloquent to Select Latest Row in Each Group Results

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have following data for `Example` model:

```
id | object_id | value | updated_at
------------------------------------------------------
 1 |         1 |   200 | 2021-04-19 01:00:00
 2 |         2 |  1200 | 2021-04-08 01:00:00
 3 |         3 |  9000 | 2021-04-07 01:00:00
 4 |         1 |   100 | 2021-04-10 01:00:00
 5 |         2 |   900 | 2021-04-13 01:00:00
 6 |         3 |  8000 | 2021-04-12 01:00:00
```

I want to get the latest updated rows grouped by object_id, for example:

```
id | object_id | value | updated_at
------------------------------------------------------
 1 |         1 |   200 | 2021-04-19 01:00:00
 5 |         2 |   900 | 2021-04-13 01:00:00
 6 |         3 |  8000 | 2021-04-12 01:00:00
```

How can I achieve that result using Eloquent?

Comment: Answered on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22562101/group-by-eloquent-orm

Comment: It's not what this question about.

Answer (score 0):

do you try?

```
$users = User::orderBy('updated_at','DESC')
            ->groupBy('object_id')
            ->get();
```

Comment: This give an error: SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'id'.

Comment: I think it is because of the active string mode, trying to get all columns, but SQL allow to select only grouped by column in strict mode request,

Try: 
    'strict' => false

in config/database.php